# What is your favorite phrase, saying, or quote expressed as code?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Do not explicitly state your saying, in comments or otherwise. Your `Code` should express itself!

For example:

```
for (Person person : people) {
    if (!HouseTypeEnum.GLASS_HOUSE.equals(person.getResidence().getHouseType())){
        throw new StonesException();
    }
}
```

Comment: `javascript:ifQuestionIsNotOnTopicForSOThenItShouldBeClosed()`

Comment: This might be appropriate on the code golf site.  Had I gotten here earlier, I would have voted to close as "off-topic" rather than "primarily opinion-based."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple expression is about as compact as I know...

```
2B || !2B
```

Or as a regex

```
/(bb|[^b]{2})/
```